# kitchen-terraform-aws testing without ssh

Tags: terraform, test-kitchen

Is there any way to test the Kitchen-terraform with aws host availability, without ssh into the aws machine?

I'm trying to bring the aws instance up by using terraform, then updating the ruby specs to verify the instance availability and security groups. But my doubt is that, is there any alternate to test the aws instance without ssh into the aws by using kitchen plugin?

Answer (score 1):

@suresh-goud thank you for your interest in the project!

It is possible to do what you are describing. If a verifier group omits the `hostnames` attribute then the associated tests will be executed on localhost, which means that you can write tests against the AWS API. The (soon to be updated) Kitchen-Terraform AWS tutorial includes an InSpec control which verifies the existence of a security group using the AWS API. https://newcontext-oss.github.io/kitchen-terraform/tutorials/amazon_provider_ec2_advance.html

Comment: That link seems to be dead